# How to show a product filter in a Shopify store

Tags: tags, shopify

I would like to filter a product based on size, color with (or) operator in Shopify and multiple options. This feature is not yet available in Shopify. Here is a sample link (non Shopify store) http://www.myntra.com/women-sandals?src=tn&nav_id=147. 
I have tried with the following example, it does work for price (between 200 to 300 and 300 to 400 price) class.

```
 $( "#price input[type='checkbox']" ).change( function() {
 var str_all= $("#all").attr("checked");
 var str_200_300= $("#200-300").attr("checked");
 var str_300_400= $("#300-400").attr("checked");
 var case_id;
    if(str_all=="checked") {
       case_id=1;
    }else if((str_200_300=="checked") && (str_300_400=="checked")) {
      case_id=4;
   }else if(str_200_300=="checked") {
      case_id=2;
   }else if(str_300_400=="checked") {
      case_id=3;
   }else {
     case_id=5;
   }

  switch(case_id) {

   case 1:
   $('.300-400').show(500);
   $('.200-300').show(500); 
 break;
   case 2:
   $('.200-300').show(500);
   $('.300-400').hide(500);
 break;
   case 3:
   $('.200-300').hide(500);
   $('.300-400').show(500);
 break;
   case 4:
   $('.300-400').show(500);
   $('.200-300').show(500); 
 break;
   case 5:
   $('.300-400').show(500);
   $('.200-300').show(500); 
 break;
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Powertools Shopify App](https://apps.shopify.com/shopify-power-tools-suite) for filters.

Power Tools can assist in basic tasks, automate processes and add new features to your store. It's a commercial app, but you can use the Free Trial which is 5 days.